# USB C charging PDO or PPS

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, usb, manjaro, battery

I have Thunderbolt 4 (and USB 4) USB C ports to charge my laptop. Is it possible to find out if it is getting charged via PDO (power delivery objects) or PPS (programmable power supply)? And what Charger voltage, current or wattage is being used.

I am seeing some random charging behavior, so I want to take a log of it.

Is it possible to find the information for Ubuntu, Fedora, Manjaro?

Comment: 99.9% of users of this website have absolutely no clue what these abbreviations are. Me neither.

Comment: PDO (power delivery objects) 
PPS (programmable power supply)

Answer (score 2):

`upower` is the command you are looking for

---

Do `upower -e` (`upower --enumerate`), copy the path that contains `battery` and then append it to `upower -i`

Example for a charging battery

> upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Sunwoda
  model:                5B10W13975
  serial:               11097
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 01 Jan 2023 16:30:13 (3 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              39.01 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         56.99 Wh
    energy-full-design:  57 Wh
    energy-rate:         43.996 W
    voltage:             16.857 V
    charge-cycles:       217
    time to full:        24.5 minutes
    percentage:          68%
    capacity:            99.9825%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1672586940  68.000  discharging
    1672586940  0.000   unknown
  History (rate):
    1672587013  43.996  charging
    1672587001  0.000   pending-charge
    1672587000  11.702  discharging
    1672586970  12.088  discharging
    1672586940  9.950   discharging
    1672586940  0.000   unknown
```

---

> Is it possible to find out if it is getting charged via PDO (power delivery objects) or PPS (programmable power supply)?

Both works together, and it's not one of the other if we follow [Belkin article](https://www.belkin.com/support-article/?articleNum=318878)

> PPS and PD protocols work together where the former can renegotiate non-standard currents and voltages between the device and the charger.

And even if that was one or the other, it is unlikely you could access the info as charging is firmawre-driven, so it would be up to the firmware to have an userspace access to that data, and apart for sth like coreboot which is open-source, this would likely never happen

Comment: Both work together that doesn't mean that both work together at the same time. Also. if we know the voltage and wattage input to the battery at any instance then we can know if its PDO or PPS